# Does xmlsec returns a 0 on exit?

Tags: xml, security, encryption, xmlsec

I need to know, if xmlsec returns 0 if file is well authenticated?

Comment: What ist the context of your question? What exactly is `xmlsec`?

Comment: @lutz - Google tells me he means http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/index.html.

Comment: Which actual function(s) of xmlsec are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that anyone cares at this point, 4.5 years later, but the question exists so it needs an answer, right?

**Yes**, xmlsec [version 1.2.19 (openssl)] returns 0 if file is authenticated:

*Success*:

```
$ xmlsec1 --verify --pubkey-cert-pem valid-cert.pem file.xml
OK
SignedInfo References (ok/all): 1/1
Manifests References (ok/all): 0/0

$ echo $?
0
```

*Fail*:

```
$ xmlsec1 --verify --pubkey-cert-pem invalid-cert.pem file.xml
FAIL
SignedInfo References (ok/all): 1/1
Manifests References (ok/all): 0/0
Error: failed to verify file "file.xml"

$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Haha, cheers! Had to become an expert on xmlsec for another question, and figured I could put my new skills to use.